# How to exclude certain values from being added to my list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am using an ultrasound sensor to continuously read distances and get their averages. Below is a part of the code:

```
distancelist = []

        while park_complete:
            distance=mdev.getSonic() #the distance is measured with this command
            Distance_measured = "%.2f" %distance
            print(Distance_measured)
            Distance_measured = float(Distance_measured)
            distancelist.append(Distance_measured)
            if Distance_measured <= 30:
                distance_avg = sum(distancelist)/len(distancelist)
                print(distance)
                print('Avg is', distance_avg)
```

All distances under 30 are being averaged. The problem is, when the sensor reads > 30 for the first time, that number gets added to my list and messes up my average value. Is there a way to exclude any value over 30 from being added to the list?
The code might confuse everyone but this is the part where my problem lies. Basically, i would like to exclude any number above a certain value from being added to my list.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Move distancelist.append(Distance_measured) inside the if block.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to skip rest of the logic and start again at the top of the loop, you can use the keyword **continue** for e.g.

```
if Distance_measured > 30:
    continue

distancelist.append(Distance_measured)

if Distance_measured <= 30:
    distance_avg = sum(distancelist)/len(distancelist)
    print(distance)
    print('Avg is', distance_avg)
```